# TSQL Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    declare @startTime datetime,@strquery nvarchar(max)
    set @startTime = '2016-01-01 10:00:00.000'      
    set @strquery =RIGHT(CONVERT(char(23),@startTime),12)
    print @strquery
    --print result: 10:15AM

    set @strquery= '2016-01-01 '+RIGHT(CONVERT(char(23),@startTime),12)
    print @strquery
    --print result: 2016-01-01  10:15AM 

    set @strquery ='2016-01-01'+RIGHT(CONVERT(char(23),@startTime),12)
    print @strquery
    --print result: 2016-01-01 10:15AM

    set @strquery =CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-01'+RIGHT(CONVERT(char(23),@startTime),12))
    print @strquery
    --print result:Jan  1 2016 10:15AM


     set @strquery ='select * from OneTransfer where CONVERT(datetime, QUOTENAME(2016-01-01,'''') +RIGHT(CONVERT(char(23),[FirstBoardTime]),12)) > ' 
     + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@startTime),'''') +' order by FirstBoardTime'
    print @strquery
    --print result:select * from OneTransfer where CONVERT(datetime, QUOTENAME(2016-01-01,'') +RIGHT(CONVERT(char(23),[FirstBoardTime]),12)) > 'Jan  1 2016 10:15AM' order by FirstBoardTime        

    --The following line failed
    execute sp_executesql  @strquery
```

I got this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date
>   and/or time from character string.

Because I need to compare hour and minute. So I transfer All of time value to the same date ex:`2016-01-01` then I can find what I need

For example find all of day of time `10:15AM`

[image: It is my Table Data]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using QUOTENAME here - looking at your printed out string, are you aware that `2016-01-01`, if not surrounded by quotes, is `2014`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I noticed that too, do you have an explanation for the `2014`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger - because they're 3 integer literals and subtracting 1 from 2016 twice produces 2014.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever... Ah, obviously, could have thought of that myself :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this: `CONVERT(datetime, QUOTENAME(2016-01-01,'')`. Besides a missing closing parenthesis, what you want to execute is: `CONVERT(datetime, '2016-01-01')`.

To achieve this you have to get the `quotename` outside of the quotes. But I don't think you need it at all.

Try this:

```
declare @startTime datetime,@strquery nvarchar(max)
    set @startTime = '2016-01-01 10:00:00.000'      

SET @strquery ='select * from OneTransfer where CONVERT( time, FirstBoardTime) > ''' 
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT( time,  + @startTime)) + ''' order by FirstBoardTime'

SELECT @strquery
```

Returns:

```
select * 
from   OneTransfer 
where  CONVERT( time, FirstBoardTime) > '10:00:00' 
order by FirstBoardTime
```

Which is I think what you are looking for. This takes the date part of the equation. If you really do need it, I think this solution will give you enough to work with.